# Bootstrap screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I am trying to create a screen layout with bootstrap CSS but being a beginner, I am struggling too much. I have a row containing two columns. I need both the columns to extend to the bottom of the available screen and should be responsive. In the second column, I need a div which is always placed at its bottom. Please see the attached image. Any help is highly appreciated.[image]

Here is what I did:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 bg-danger">
                left
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]">{{x}}</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 bg-info">
                right
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]"> content {{x}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="nav bg-warning">nav</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The code you have so far would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it stretch full viewport you give them all a height of 100%

Another option is to use viewport units `vh` on the columns

```css
html, body, .container, .row, .row > div {
  height: 100%;
}
.bg-info {
  position: relative;
}
.bg-info .nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);   /* 2 * 15px padding */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 bg-danger">
                left
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 bg-info">
                right
              
                <div class="nav bg-warning">nav</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks @LGSon.

Answer (score 2):

check this out.

```css
.constant{
  position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
  width:100%;
  border: 2px solid #f60;
  height: 40px;
  }
.cover-viewport {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 cover-viewport">
  <!-- your content goes here-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 cover-viewport">
  <!-- your content goes here-->
    <div class="constant"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Hope the code below helps:

```css
.constant{
  position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <!-- your content goes here-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
  <!-- your content goes here-->
    <div class="constant"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: did you include Bootstrap CDN?

Comment: yes I did. both columns didn't stretch to bottom and the constant div appears at right side of the second column.

Comment: that's because you didn't include your content in child `div` s. Without content if you want the `div` s to cover the screen then you need to explicitly specify height for both child `div` s.

Comment: The child div is ok but the columns didn't stretch.